# java / netbeans timer?

Tags: java

I am working with stocks. I have an api (pre written), in which I have adjusted the code a bit to suit my requirements, such as getting tick feed to my requirement (one tick is minimum movement up or down +-.01 cent).

TICK is the way to describe a stock movement e.g. TICK charts etc. In very simple language it's just a movement/price change, nothing else.

The program prints out to the console when there has been three up ticks in a row or down ticks in a row.

I would like to know, how do I configure my api for a break out?  That means three ticks (price movement) or 4 ticks in a particular direction (last 4 prices of a stock were greater than the previous ones, e.g. $1.01 then $1.02 then $1.03 then 1.04) but all within a time frame, say 500 or 300 milliseconds.

Is there a timer function?
The api is written in net beans / java

Comment: The wording of this question is very confusing. I think I understand what you're getting at, but you may want to edit your question (maybe give an example if you're struggling with the wording).

Comment: I *think* what you're trying to ask is this: I have multiple events (up and down "ticks"). I want to have the program react when there are 3 up or down ticks (in a row) within a certain time frame. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: thank you for the feedback, will make changes very shortly

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: hi, sorry guys,, my first time. this person is onto it - CHRIS "I think what you're trying to ask is this: I have multiple events (up and down "ticks"). I want to have the program react when there are 3 up or down ticks (in a row) within a certain time frame. How can this be accomplished? "

Comment: What information is contained with a "tick"? Does it come with a time-stamp of some sort? An amount of change? It sounds like all you need is a couple of simple if statements and you're set. Or is the information coming in in "real-time", and you have to record the time of occurrence yourself in your program? If so, you can easily get system time though GC might mess you up at times.

Comment: yea doesnt come with a timestamp, and yea its real time, just when the price changes, i get a print out on the console, LAST PRICE =(blah blah)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to periodically execute tasks or delay tasks, there's [`java.util.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) that provides a way to delay or repeat tasks, and [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) that requires Java 6, but allows much more fine-grained control over scheduling and queueing strategies.

Also, with `ExecutorService`, you can get pretty good control over when things happen if you program *very* carefully, but it's not designed by default to meet [real-time](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/rt_pt1/) guarantees so you should research Java for real-time systems if that's what you need.

EDIT

Re "tick", if you can keep track of the times of the last three prices changes, can't you just interpret a change as a tick if all those prices are within delta-time of the time of the event?

There is no core library support for such a thing, but it shouldn't require complicated uses of futures.

Comment: tick is not involved in this program, only thing involved is CHANGE OF PRICE everytime the price changes, that a tick, that was just for explanation, so if the price changes three times(i can just use, for int i, >3... ) to store last three event changes, but i want to know if i can put a timer on it, if the event changes or if it happens within half a second, thats a stock breakout. my apologies but i am very much surprised by such freaking quick responses on this website. thanks

Comment: yup thats one way to keep track using delta time

Answer (score 0):

I would declare a few variables such as

```
int consecutiveTickCount = 0;
long timeOfFirstTick;
long timeOfLastTick;
boolean lastTickUp = false;
```

Then with each tick,

- Get the direction of the tick
- Get the time of the tick by `System.currentTimeMillis()` and put in timeOfLastTick
- Check the direction against lastTickUp. If in opposite direction, set timeOfFirstTick to timeOfLastTick just obtained, set lastTickUp to true or false depending on the direction of this last tick, and set consecutiveTickCount to 1
- If both in same direction, increment consecutiveTickCount.
- If consecutiveTickCount == 3, check the timeOfFirstTick vs timeOfLastTick. If difference < your minimum, then you've got a "break out".
- Note that garbage collection can mess up real time data collection.